# Name of this plant

Tags: botany, species-identification

I contact you all with great pain because my cute little plant is slowly deterioriating. I need you help. Do any of you know the name of this plant and/or the caring specifications for it? If it helps, it stays in South America.

Thanks you all.

[image]

Comment: Do you think it is native in South Africa or do you think it could be ornemental? If it is ornemental, you will have better chance of getting an answer on [Gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

That's a crassulacean native to Madagascar, called [*Bryophyllum daigremontianum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryophyllum_daigremontianum).

It has a [synonym](http://keyserver.lucidcentral.org/weeds/data/media/Html/bryophyllum_daigremontianum.htm), *Kalanchoe daigremontiana* (funily enough, bot [Portuguese](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe_daigremontiana) and [Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe_daigremontiana) Wikipedia pages — since you are in South America — use this synonym).

Its common names are "Mother of thousands". "Mother of millions", "Mexican hat plant" and "Devil's backbone".

[image]

Regarding how to care your succulent, unfortunately this is *off topic* at Bio SE (but have a look at [my comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60638/name-of-this-plant/60643#comment110831_60643) below).

Comment: PS: regarding you poor plant, here is an advice from a guy that normally kills his succulents: you're probably adding **too much** water.